# swapping font awesome fonts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i am trying to create a star rating list using jQuery, html and css. at the moment the icons appear through a class  im assuming this just calls the class from the font awesome link i used
(`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />`)

i have tried but i cant find any way to swap the star for a basic asterisk ive tried to used content : " * "; and other types of content tags that refer to asterisks but to no avail

due to the link being a web link and the font isnt actually called inside the code im having trouble changing them

essentially i need to remove the fa fa-star part and have a normal asterisk there, and i cant have it outside the class or my Jquery will display any stars when triggered

```css
.stars {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 180px;
}

.checked {
  color: #F0191C;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="stars">
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.stars span.fa.fa-star').removeClass("fa fa-star").text("*");`

Comment: ideally it would be changed in html but ill look into this, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "changed in html"...? Are you looking for a pure CSS-based solution? In that case use `.stars span::before { content: "*"; }`

Comment: Thanks , your js method worked wonders